# Flash webcam chatroom script?

Tags: flash, webcam

I am looking for a free script that I could use as a webcam chat. I am not looking for anything too complicated. Basically, all I need is a small flash app that I can use to display the same video, coming in from a webcam elsewhere, on another page.

I also want the script to be hosted on my website, so no going through other websites.

Anyone know of anything I could use? Doesn't have to be free.  I have a pretty good knowledge of PHP and Javascript (& Jquery). However, I don't know flash. Think I should just learn it?